# How to query Mixpanel from C#

Tags: c#, post, webclient, mixpanel

I am pretty new to web access from C# and completely new to Mixpanel. I am trying to run a query with this code:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
  byte[] creds = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<my API secret>:");
  wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(creds));
  var reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
  reqparm.Add("script", "function main() { return Events({\"from_date\":\"2016-10-01\",\"to_date\":\"2016-10-167\"}).reduce(mixpanel.reducer.count()); }");
  byte[] responsebytes = wc.UploadValues("https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql", "POST", reqparm);
}
```

The query is taken directly from this `Mixpanel` sample:

```
function main()
{
  return Events
  ({
    from_date: "2016-01-04",
    to_date: "2016-01-04"
  }).reduce(mixpanel.reducer.count());
}
```

I've tried lots of variations on the above, but `UploadValues` always returns 400 (Bad Request). What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in one of the dates that I didn't notice ("2016-10-167").